# Sublime text html tidy configuration

Tags: sublimetext2, htmltidy

I am using sublime text for some time. 
When I try to use the HTML tidy plugin to indent the html file I observe that all my newlines are automatically removed by it.

Is there a way to stop that? I don't want to remove the newlines thru the plugin. I could not find any setting which could do that for me.

Should i go for some other HTML formater?

Comment: I know this is not what you want, but have you considered removing blank lines from the HTML? The indentation is really helpful to distinguish different sections of the content.

Comment: Some tags don't start from a new line which makes it look ugly. That is why I manually create blank lines. Tags such as "script" etc.